# Hide form and show div

Tags: javascript, php, forms, hide, show

So I have this

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $error = "test";
    }
?>
<div id="first" class="1">
  <form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <p>
      <label for="textfield">Text Field:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" formmethod="POST">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>

<div id="second" class="2" style="display:none">
  <?php echo $error; ?>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myform").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#first").hide();
            $("#second").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

So, everything is OK with javascript, the form is hiding, div is displaying, but the php isnt working. The form is submitting only to js and not to php.

Comment: You need ajax with that bro.

Answer (score 1):

You need an action, it's not doing anything because it's TOLD to not do anything

```
<form action="name_of_this_file.php" method="post" id="myform">
```

or

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="myform">
```

Comment: Why not just leave the `action` empty?

Comment: Nah, thats not the problem with the action.

Comment: 1. is it actually a php file, or 2. is your server set to run php code from within an html file. If you're not going to set an action remove that attribute enitrely

Comment: Yes, of course. Im using shared hosting if is it matter.

Comment: Are you also aware you're not allowing the form to submit after preventing it within jquery? You don't submit the form after preventing it. You need to manually submit it if you want it to submit via php after e.preventDefault(e)

Comment: Then how i can hide form and show the div and also send the form via php?

Comment: Lookup how to use AJAX, you can create a php file separate and call that file via ajax on hide or on show etc

Answer (score 0):

You have no php action handler listed.